# Why does changing a property from the mediaRecorder.onstop event handler not change the page?

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to transfer functionality to Angular, I ran into an interesting problem, when setting a property from a method, everything works fine, but when setting from an event, it changes, but is not displayed on the page. However, if you call this property after that in any method, everything is displayed at once,

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emqw1a?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

-- Reference --
Property - record; 
Handler hangs on streamRecorder, onstop event; 
Using one-way binding to the src element of video 
Using [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to generate a secure link using window.URL.createUrlObject(blob)

I would be grateful even for a tomato in the face!) I ran through the docks in a few days, my knowledge is still at the level of guides from the docks.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be scope/change detection. Something screwy with the particular `reader.onstop` vs `reader.addEventListener('stop', ...)`

Change from

```
this.streamRecorder.onstop = () => {
    ...
}
```

to

```
this.streamRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
    ...
}
```

and it works.

Comment: very interesting ahaha, thx you!